# Get the max(datetime) in Pyspark

Tags: datetime, pyspark, max

I have a dataset like this :

| category | datetime | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | date1 | 10 |
| a | date2 | 30 |
| a | date3 | 20 |
| a | date4 | 50 |
| a | date5 | 30 |
| b | date6 | 20 |
| b | date7 | 15 |
| b | date8 | 30 |
| b | date9 | 40 |
| c | date10 | 10 |
| c | date11 | 10 |
| c | date12 | 30 |

And I want to get for each categoy the datetime of the max(value)

In this example I want to get this :

| category | datetime | value | datetimeMax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | date1 | 10 | date4 |
| a | date2 | 30 | date4 |
| a | date3 | 20 | date4 |
| a | date4 | 50 | date4 |
| a | date5 | 30 | date4 |
| b | date6 | 20 | date9 |
| b | date7 | 15 | date9 |
| b | date8 | 30 | date9 |
| b | date9 | 40 | date9 |
| c | date10 | 10 | date12 |
| c | date11 | 10 | date12 |
| c | date12 | 30 | date12 |

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What if there is a tie?  also please share your code that you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`MAX_BY`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#max_by) in `pyspark >= 3.3.0`

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

w = (
    Window
    .partitionBy('category')
    .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
)
mdt = F.max_by('datetime', 'value').over(w)
df2 = df.withColumn('datetime_max', mdt)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max

df = df.join(
    df.groupby('category'). \
    agg(max('value').alias('datetimeMax')), \
    on=['category'])
df.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `window` functions(`row_number,max`) for this case, by defining the partition by on `category` and order by on `value` descending.

- `when(row_number().over(w) == 1,` -> when row_number=1 then get datetime value otherwise keep as null
- `max(when(row_number().over(w) == 1,col("datetime")))` -> get max value for the window and populate on all rows

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

w = Window.partitionBy('category').orderBy(desc('value'))

w = Window.partitionBy('category').orderBy(desc('value'))

df.withColumn("datetimeMax",max(when(row_number().over(w) == 1,col("datetime"))).over(w)).show(100,False)

#+--------+--------+-----+-----------+
#|category|datetime|value|datetimeMax|
#+--------+--------+-----+-----------+
#|a       |date4   |50   |date4      |
#|a       |date2   |30   |date4      |
#|a       |date5   |30   |date4      |
#|a       |date3   |20   |date4      |
#|a       |date1   |10   |date4      |
#+--------+--------+-----+-----------+
```